# AWS - Aurora replicas

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Scenario:

- I have two reader-aurora replicas.
- I make many calls to my system (high load)
- I see only one replica working at 99.30%, but the other one is not doing
  anything at all

Why?, is because this second replica is ONLY to prevent failures of the first one?, cannot be possible to make both to share the load?

Comment: Is your application configured to send writes to the Aurora write endpoint, and reads to the Aurora read endpoint?

Comment: Yes. It was working with only one replica actually. Then I added a second one, and still is using the first one. From my understanding Aurora in this case is creating a cluster, so I shouldn't change anything in my code. The cluster should distribute the read requests (maybe I'm wrong of course)

Comment: Each instance has a hostname, and the cluster has a hostname for the writer and one for "any" reader, [as I once described at Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/a/809299/153161).  Are you using the `cluster-ro` hostname?

Comment: The read requests aren't distributed automatically. You have to send them specifically to the load-balanced reader endpoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your RDS console, you should be able to look at each of the 3 instances

1. aurora-databasecluster-xxx.cluster-yyy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
2. zz0.yyy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
3. zz1.yyy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306

If you look at the cluster tab you will see two end points and the 2nd is the following:
aurora-databasecluster-xxx.cluster-ro-yyy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

Aurora allows you do either explicitly get to specific read replica.  This would allow a set of read only nodes for OLTP performance and another set for data analysis - with long running queries that won't impact performance.

If you use the -ro end point, it should balance cross all read only nodes or you can have your code take a list of read only connection strings and do your own randomizer.  I would have expected the ro to be better...but I am not yet familiar on their load balancing technique (fewest connections, round robin, etc)