# Fail over on an Aurora RDS read-only replica with minimal downtime

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I'm wondering what's the best practice to handle the failover of an Aurora RDS Instance. I have a writer instance with two reader instances connected. The three instances are in three different AZs.

Should I just select my desired instance and click "Failover"? What's the expected downtime? Can I do this while receiving production traffic?

Comment: Are you using the "cluster" and "cluster-ro" hostnames as intended?  See my comment [below this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41655456/1695906) and discussion of the cluster hostnames in more detail in [this Server Fault answer](http://serverfault.com/a/809299/153161) to different question.

Answer (score 1):

Failover is in principle instant - the very first thing AWS does is updates the DNS record so it points to the failover instant.

One thing to be aware of, though, is that a read replica is written to asynchronously, not synchronously, which means it will lag your main database by some level.

If you *really* want to do this whilst recieving production traffic, you in principle can, but you need to make sure any applications will reconnect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the Aurora service is it already had redundancy.   Actually redundant redundancy.  If one fails it will take 30 sec. for it to switch over to another data center.

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/

> Amazon Aurora's storage is fault-tolerant and self-healing. Six copies
>   of your data are replicated across three Availability Zones and
>   continuously backed up to Amazon S3